# tabbing out of menu item in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript

When we are using tab key and we reach the site actions or welcome menu and press enter we can get inside the menu and then we can tab through the options.The issue I am facing is that when the last item is reached and I press tab it goes to the first item in the menu instead of moving to the next element outside the menu.Can someone please tell me how I can achieve this

```
 <menu id="zz4_FeatureMenuTemplate1" largeiconmode="true">

        <ie:menuitem id="zz5_MenuItem_CreateDocLib" menugroupid="200" description="Create a place to store and share documents." text="New Document Library" onmenuclick="if (LaunchCreateHandler('DocLib')) { GoToPage('\u002fview\u002f_layouts/new.aspx?FeatureId={00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101}&amp;ListTemplate=101') }" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/NewDocLibHH.png" type="option"></ie:menuitem>
        <ie:menuitem id="zz6_MenuItem_CreateSite" menugroupid="200" description="Create a site for a team or project." text="New Site" onmenuclick="if (LaunchCreateHandler('Site')) { STSNavigate('\u002fview\u002f_layouts/newsbweb.aspx') }" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/newweb32.png" type="option"></ie:menuitem>
        <ie:menuitem id="zz7_MenuItem_Create" menugroupid="200" description="Create other types of pages, lists, libraries, and sites." text="More Options..." onmenuclick="if (LaunchCreateHandler('All')) { STSNavigate('\u002fview\u002f_layouts/create.aspx') }" type="option"></ie:menuitem>

        <ie:menuitem id="zz8_MenuItem_ViewAllSiteContents" menugroupid="300" description="View all libraries and lists in this site." text="View All Site Content" onmenuclick="STSNavigate2(event,'/view/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx');" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/allcontent32.png" type="option"></ie:menuitem>
        <ie:menuitem id="zz9_MenuItem_SitePermissions" menugroupid="300" description="Give people access to this site." text="Site Permissions" onmenuclick="STSNavigate2(event,'/view/_layouts/user.aspx');" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/Permissions32.png" type="option"></ie:menuitem>
        <ie:menuitem id="zz10_MenuItem_Settings" menugroupid="300" description="Access all settings for this site." text="Site Settings" onmenuclick="STSNavigate2(event,'/view/_layouts/settings.aspx');" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/settingsIcon.png" type="option"></ie:menuitem>
    </menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape to close the window then tab to go to the next item.

Comment: Thanks but the issue is users expect normal tab functionality when tabbing through the items so at the end of the item list they would expect the tab would take them to the next element .

Comment: If they expect to tab and hit enter to open a window, then they should expect to have to do something to get out of the window and continue on tabbing through the page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I cannot actually tell the users what they should do ..I have to code according to how the business wants it .